# VBA: Copying picture from another sheet problem; clipboard not clearing?

Tags: excel, vba, image, copy, paste

I have two worksheet; `cal` and `sketch`. In `sketch`, I have two pictures; `Picture 1` and `Picture 2`. In worksheet cal, I have a cell with a dropdown list; contents of the list are `'Port'` and `'Starboard'`.

I would like to have Picture 1 or Picture 2 copy to `cal.Cells(25, 1)` when the dropdown changes; replacing whatever picture was there before hand.

I have the code working for the changing of the cell and it copies a Picture. It just ALWAYS copies Picture 1.

```
Sub import_sketch()

    Dim my_sketch As Picture

    If Cells(8, 27) = "Port" Then

        Set my_sketch = sketch.Pictures("Picture 1")
        my_sketch.Copy
        cal.Cells(25, 1).PasteSpecial

    End If

    If Cells(8, 27) = "Starboard" Then

        Set my_sketch = sketch.Pictures("Picture 2")
        my_sketch.Copy
        cal.Cells(25, 1).PasteSpecial

    End If

End Sub
```

Currently, the script just pastes in Picture 1, no matter what the contents are in the dropdown. I know the Starboard If statement is working. It appears the clipboard doesn't clear and just copies what is first in the list? Not sure.

Comment: Try Debugging through your Code using `F8`. You will see what is happening at each step.

Comment: My Guess is that you are not deleting the Existing picture on `Cal` sheet. But you should go through the code step by step to identify the problem.

Comment: Removing Set my_sketch = sketch.Pictures("Picture 1") in favour of sketch.Shapes("Picture 1").Copy seems to have done the job. Now I just need to delete all the pictures on the cal worksheet prior to PasteSpecial the new one in?

Comment: Yes Exactly .. otherwise they will be accumulated one on another.

Comment: `Dim sh As Shape    

For Each sh In cal.Shapes    

    sh.Delete    

Next` ... Simple loop will do that

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already point out, your problem is that you copy the correct picture but don't delete the old ones.

However, instead of copying (and deleting) the images over and over again, why don't you copy both of them into your sheet once and then simply set the `Visible`-property to show the image you want and hide the other?

Name the pictures `picStarboard` and `picPort` and change your code to

```
With cal 
    .Shapes("picStarboard").Visible = (.Cells(8, 27) = "Starboard")
    .Shapes("picPort").Visible = (.Cells(8, 27) = "Port")
End With
```